# Help needed in writing Meta data information from the image sequence to the converted video in blender

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[image: Image Sequence Name]

I want to display each individual filename in my converted image sequence to video output in every frame of the blender. I tried with the sequence of numbers also. But it shows the same file name. I tried with all the metadata options. But no luck. Anyone there to help me!. Herewith, I attached the screenshot for the same.

[image: Blender Settings]